# Cerrar ojetos, datasets, datatables, ... en c#

Tags: c#

Mi duda es la siguiente. Yo, cuando programo una aplicación, abro muchos datasets, datatables, connections, commands, etc... es un largo listado. Entonces, yo no se cuales se han de destruir porque ya no se utilizan y ocuparan memoria y cuales no y, además, no se como destruir cada uno. A los objetos connection, command, ... y todos aquellos que utilizo cuando llamo a una base de datos los destruyo ponindo "con = null", pero creo que eso no sirve para nada.

¿Me podéis enseñar este tema?

Gracias

Comment: Una variable de un objeto es un puntero a la memoria, cuando lo llevas a null eliminas el puntero pero no lo que está en la memoria. Las aplicaciones .net tienen Garbage Collector que se encargan automáticamente de liberar la memoria de elementos que no tienen punteros, puedes forzar este proceso usando GC.Collect(); (yo nunca lo he utilizado). Luego elementos con conexión casi todos tienen una función close(), además existe el using y también tienes la función Dispose() que implementan algunas clases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como menciono @Yussef en el comentario, el Garbage collector se encarga de liberar memoria, pero no elimina objetos así que debes complementarlo implementando la interfaz **IDisposable**. ¿Qué? Sí debes implementar esa interfaz para poder eliminar los objetos que el GC no lo hace.

La forma más sencilla (y la que siempre uso) es la palabra reservada using. Para el uso con DataTable sería algo así:

```
public void CargarDatos()
{
    using (SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection("CADENA_CONEXION_AQUI"))
    {
        string consulta = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection))
        {
            DataTable dtCliente = new DataTable("Clientes");
            try
            {
            conexion.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dtClientes);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            conexion.Close()
        } //Elimina objeto adapter despues de su uso
    } //Elimina objeto conexion despues de su uso
}
```

Para esos casos, el using hace que se invoque a **IDisposable** para que elimine los objetos **SqlConnection**, **SqlDataAdapter**.

El **using** solo puede ser utilizado por clases que implementan la interfaz **IDisposable**, caso contrario no puede ser utilizado.